# Not understanding javascript window.frames.Array

Tags: javascript, iframe

Looking at below piece of code

```
 var _Array = window.frames[window.frames.length-1].Array;
```

I truly don't understand what this means. I understand what Array is in javascript.. But what is this code doing? I get the window.frames[] part. What does adding .Array at the end do??

Please let me know. thank you.

Comment: I am sorry?? Could you please elaborate? Please forget the part of assigning this right expression to the variable _Array

Comment: where did you see this code? `window.frames` returns a `FrameList` pseudo-array, but there is no such `Array` property on this object, as far as I know.

Comment: Is that code possibly trying to get the `Array` object from the last frame in the list of frame in the current window?

Comment: saw it on the code example from this video I am studying from. Ok, so if this code is wrong, then, please forgive me. I will move on.

Comment: Do you know what the code is attempting to do?

Comment: Pretty sure it will get the `Array` constructor from inside the last frame on a page, but this code is less-than great.

Comment: This was used to demonstrate that  when you create another var using new _Array(1,2,3), that newly created var is not instanceof Array

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara - that's what I thought

Comment: Yep, that's correct, it will not be an instance of another window's Array constructor. So what don't you understand?

Comment: My question is I guess, what is the need for tagging on ".Array" at the end of that original statement? What did that do?? so, I guess difference between window.frames[window.frames.length-1]  VS winow.frames[window.frames.length-1].Array is ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might become more-clear if we break it down a bit.

```
// Get the global window object for the last frame on the page.
var iframeWindow = window.frames[window.frames.length-1];

// Get the Array constructor for the iframe window.    
var _Array = iframeWindow.Array;
```

`window.frames` is an array-like object, which contains all the frames in the window. Once you have a reference to one of them, you can access the frames global variables as properties of that object, just like you can access the globals for the current window through the `window` object. In this case, the frames global `Array` constructor is being accessed.

The equivalent code for getting the `Array` constructor for the current window would be:

```
var _Array = window.Array;
```

Comment: Just one question. Doing var newArray = new _Array(1,2,3), _Array is essentially something(in this case iframeWindow).Array    That's fine. So when you do var foo = new Array(1,2,3)..    in this case, can I think of this as.. (something).Array..  ? but then what is something in this case? Window?   (sorry, if this question seems really stupid. I perfectly know how to construct array but this question really threw entire my understanding of object and array in javascript into gutter..

Comment: @user3502374 `(something)` would be `window`. `window.Array` is the same as the global `Array`.

Comment: that does make sense now I remember.. as function by itself calling, "this" becomes window.. so in this case. similar concept I hope

Comment: Array by itself, it's scope is the global.